# Chartist's pie labels are misplaced, and i can't debug it

Tags: javascript, json, charts, chartist.js

I'm trying to make charts using Json data fetched from some `php` page.

Specifically, I want to display a pie chart with a label of what each part is, and the percentages it represents.

I followed the chartist examples, and ended up with this codepen :

`https://codepen.io/orsucciu/pen/qBdrjow`

The labels are small, misplaced, and the percentage doesn't appear!

I checked the debug console, but nothing was raised.

I also added a `console.log` inside my LabelInterpolation to see but it's not sending anything... So I suspect it's coming from there, but I don't know what exactly is the problem :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codepen.io/SkyDieRay/pen/BaNWdmr

```
data = JSON.parse('{"orphans":17,"0":4,"1":7,"3":1,"aTraiter":2,"aValider":3,"Valided":4,"retourBO":5}');
```

I played around a bit and your buggy values were showing there because of data with 0% in the chart, hence why all of it was in the same place.
I changed the data to give them values and it looks normal now.

For showing the percentage I added this to the responsiveOptions.
Also, replace value with dat.series[index]. Value there is just the keys of your data, not the values. So you are diving strings most of the time, which is why you get NaN% as a result there.

```
labelInterpolationFnc: function(value, index) {
  var percentage = Math.round(dat.series[index] / dat.series.reduce(sum) * 100) + '%';
  return dat.labels[index] + ' ' + percentage;
}
```

Comment: ahhhhhh it must be because of some divide by zero thing. Of course! thank you ! (but i'm still suprised no error showed up)

Comment: I updated the code a little more to show the percentages as you wanted. The problem with your labelInterpolationFnc was that Chartist.Pie was using your default responsiveOptions not the options.